# Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0

Tags: android

Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable

Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.1.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}





plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.0' apply false
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin' version '2.0.1' apply false
}
```

Comment: Does solution for similar problems asked here already doesn't work ? ... [there is image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugp7v.png) in the question, here on stackoverflow, which has 397 upvotes ... and the answer with 306 ...

Comment: My Issue was Resolve. This issue come due some Adding new dependencies and my internet is not workings properly so that dependencies not download. after  change internet connection it working